# OAuth2 support in the Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta

I was looking to understand if Okta can support OAuth2. 
My requirement is that for salesforce users(which are based on the OAuth2 authentication) should be allowed to SSO(single sign on) in the my product which uses the Okta as the identity provider.

Comment: What language are you using? Do you have a repository?

Answer (score 0):

Okta does not current support OAuth 2.0 for this use case. However, you can use SAML to SSO into Salesforce. The Salesforce Deployment Guide [see link below] describes how to accomplish this.

https://support.okta.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/20802921-Salesforce-com-Deployment-Guide?id=kA0F0000000AYEG&q=salesforce&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! Yes the SAML can be used to SSO in to Salesforce. However I was looking for salesforce users to SSO in to our domain(based on Okta).